# Vlookup where 2 columns match values

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, gs-vlookup

I am comparing two sheets. If column A and column B both match, then I want to return column C. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

basically like this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2:A&B2:B, {sheet1!A2:A&sheet1!B2:B, sheet1!C2:C}, 2, 0)))
```